# object Object at handleError graphql using amplify

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

I created a graphQL API for my amplify project following [this Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/connect-to-api/).

I've followed all the steps layed out here but whenever I try to call the `createItem` function I show below I get the following error:

```
ERROR
[object Object]
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69505:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69528:7
```

I think it's because I'm passing in the wrong object type and it should be of type `CreateApplicationInput!`, but I don't know where that objects defined or how to create an instnace of it. This is my first time doing full-stack dev with javascript, so any help would be really appreciated!

I have the following function that's called when a button is clicked to use graphQL to create a new item in my backend DB:

```
const client = generateClient();

async function createItem() {
  const app = {name: "test", description: "first one"}

  // let CreateApplicationInput = {name: "test", description: "first one"}
  // const test = new CreateApplicationInput();
  // test.name = "test"
  // test.description = "idk"


  await client.graphql({
    query: createApplication,
    variables: {
      input: app
    }
  });
  // console.log(result);
}
```

The `createApplication` function that's used is here and was automatically generated by amplify:

```
export const createApplication = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateApplication(
    $input: CreateApplicationInput!
    $condition: ModelApplicationConditionInput
  ) {
    createApplication(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      name
      description
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      __typename
    }
  }
`;
```

And this is what my graphQL schema looks like:

```
type Application @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```